# "bb.system.phone" is not installed

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'am new to blackberry cascades and was trying my hands on call functionality.
However after running my sample program, the following error is occuring:

```
import bb.cascades 1.4
import bb.system.phone 1.0

Page {
Container {
    layout: StackLayout {
    }

    Button {
        id: callButton
        text: "Call me"
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

        onClicked: {
            phone.requestDialpad("(519) 555-0100")

        }
    }
}
attachedObjects: [
    Phone {
        id: phone
    }
  ]
}
```

and in my .pro file

```
LIBS += -lbbsystem
```

the error I'am facing is: `module "bb.system.phone" is not installed`

My program is loading but a black screen is displayed.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Error-module-quot-bb-system-phone-quot-is-not-installed/td-p/3078209

Answer (score 0):

Since the Phone class is a C++ class, the first thing we must do is to register the Phone class as qmlRegisterType for QML access.
[See this for help](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/#usingcclassesinqml)

Add this line to main.cpp

qmlRegisterType("bb.system.phone", 1, 0, "Phone");

[For more help](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development-Knowledge/BlackBerry-10-Developer-s-Guide-to-Telephony-APIs/ta-p/2734969)